# Extracting city and state from location column, hit AttributeError instead

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I want to clean the `location` column, removing the zip codes, but I get the following error when extracting and using the regex:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Here is a sample dataframe with just the location column:

```
In [52]: df
Out[52]:
                       location
0    New Feliciamouth, WA 16422
1           Bakerfurt, CO 76376
2  Lake Elizabethview, GA 59017
3      Robertschester, TX 92366
4       Robinsonmouth, AL 99445
5        North Connor, AZ 79552
6          Morganstad, WA 73506
7         New Roberto, IA 11832
8         Collierstad, DC 22151
9          Reneemouth, NJ 93901
```

(this is data generated randomly to illustrate the problem).

I want to  make the different cities appear as:

```
New Feliciamouth, WA
       Bakerfurt, CO
```

etc.

I'm using this code:

```
def get_city(address):
    pattern = r'(.+\,\w.+)\w.+)'
    return address.str.extract(pattern,flags=re.I)

location = df['location']        
location.apply(get_city)
location.head()
```

However, I get the exception when I run this:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-cdec695003fd> in <module>
      4
      5 location = df['location']
----> 6 location.apply(get_city)
      7 location.head()

.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   4043             else:
   4044                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 4045                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   4046
   4047         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-62-cdec695003fd> in get_city(address)
      1 def get_city(address):
      2     pattern = r'(.+\,\w.+)\w.+)'
----> 3     return address.str.extract(pattern,flags=re.I)
      4
      5 location = df['location']

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Or when removing .str before extracting I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-bfed6f810b40> in <module>
      4
      5 location = df['location']
----> 6 location.apply(get_city)
      7 location.head()

.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   4043             else:
   4044                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 4045                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   4046
   4047         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-63-bfed6f810b40> in get_city(address)
      1 def get_city(address):
      2     pattern = r'(.+\,\w.+)\w.+)'
----> 3     return address.extract(pattern,flags=re.I)
      4
      5 location = df['location']

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'extract'
```

Comment: Your pattern has mismatched parentheses

Comment: I've replaced the image in your question with a randomly-generated sample of addresses. In future, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](//stackoverflow.com/q/20109391) for great tips on how to produce a good [mre] for us to help you. Note that we only needed the `location` column, the rest of your data doesn't matter here.

Answer (score 0):

`Series.apply()` passes *each value* to your `get_city()` function. You can't use `Series.str....` functions on a single string value, you don't have the whole series.

Since you have a vectorised string function for this, **don't use `Series.apply()`**, just use the `Series.str.extract` method *directly* on the `location` column:

```
pattern = r'([^,]+,\s*\w+)\s*\d*'
location = df['location'].str.extract(pattern, flags=re.I)
location.head()
```

Note that I also altered your regex pattern:

- There was an extra `)` in there, which makes the pattern invalid because the opening `(` for it was missing.
- I replaced `.+` at the start with `[^,]+` so the comma is never matched.
- I inserted `\s*` after the comma to allow for whitespace between the comma and the state.
- I replaced the `\w.+` with just `\w+`, you don't want a letter followed by anything, you want only letters. Consider matching only uppercase letters here, however, and limit the length. `[A-Z]{,3}` would allow for zero to three uppercase letters.
- The zipcode is now matched by a series of digits. The pattern can still match additional characters after that but those would not be part of the extracted value.

Demo using the one full column value that's actually visible in your screenshot:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: import re

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame([["Atlanta, GA 30301"]], columns=["location"])

In [4]: pattern = r'([^,]+,\s*\w+)\s*\d*'

In [5]: df['location'].str.extract(pattern, flags=re.I)
Out[5]:
                        0
0    New Feliciamouth, WA
1           Bakerfurt, CO
2  Lake Elizabethview, GA
3      Robertschester, TX
4       Robinsonmouth, AL
5        North Connor, AZ
6          Morganstad, WA
7         New Roberto, IA
8         Collierstad, DC
9          Reneemouth, NJ
```